# How to clear textbox values from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using an ascx page through which I'm sending mails to clients.

After entering To, CC, BCC, Subject and matter, I'm clicking the "Send Mail" button.

In that code, I'm calling `clear()` function where I'm clearing the text values after sending the mail.

But, after the textboxes are cleared, when I press "F5" or refresh button in "Firefox" browser, the page reloads and all the textboxes values retains.. Its not happening in "Chrome" browser..

So, I used javascript to clear the values..

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("<%= txtTO.ClientID %>").value = "";
    document.getElementById("<%= txtCC.ClientID %>").value = "";
    document.getElementById("<%= txtBCC.ClientID %>").value = "";
    document.getElementById("<%= txtSubject.ClientID %>").value = "";
};
```

Now its cleared..

But now I got new problem.. I'm calling this same page from another link also.. In that I'm loading BCC values on page load event.. But as I'm clearing in javascript, the values got cleared after page loads.. The value has to be displayed when calling from another link..

How to solve this problem..?

Comment: you can add the BCC values in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: you need to pass the input values via ajax in an interval to your db and then update the input value again via ajax in the other page, that's the theory!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field. Set the value to "1" in javascript onclick event of SendEmail button and set it back to zero in SendEmail server side event and put condition on hidden field value to execute SendEmail server side code.

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnSent" />
```

*Javascript*

```
function onClickOfSendEmail()
{
     document.getElementById("<%= hdnSent.ClientID %>").value == "1"
}
```

*Code behind*

```
void btnSendMail_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(hdnSent.Value != "1")
       return;
     hdnSent.Value = "0";
     //your code
}
```

Comment: You are resisting the mail send itself. Its not I needed. My scenario is simple; When I'm loading the page for first time, if any values had to be displayed means it should be displayed. After sending mail, if I reload the page by pressing F5 means, the values should not display..

Comment: Also this problem occurs in Firefox browser only.. Not in Chrome browser.. So if you are working out means, use Firefox browser..

Comment: Check the hidden field value when f5 is pressed it should be 0 if send button is not cliked, similarly you can set hidden field value for other postback commands to distinguish those from f5